# Does changing an item inside a list will trigger the state change in Riverpod Flutter?

Tags: riverpod

I have a list of products and want to change some fields inside list. I am curious if this change can be emitted with Riverpod in Flutter. It seems it is not working even I use `ref.watch` for the provider.

```
@freezed
class ApplicationState with _$ApplicationState {
  const factory ApplicationState({
    @Default([]) List<Product> products,
  }) = _ApplicationState;
}


class ApplicationNotifier extends StateNotifier<ApplicationState> {

  ApplicationNotifier() : super(const ApplicationState());


    setProductQuantity({required int i, required String productId}) {

        final changedProduct = state.products
          .map((product) => product.id == productId
            ? Product(
                id: product.id,
                title: product.title,
                price: product.price,
                description: product.description,
                availableQuantity: product.availableQuantity,
                quantity: i,
              )
            : product)
        .toList();

    state = state.copyWith(products: changedProduct);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```dart
state = ApplicationState(products: changedProduct);
```

instead of

```dart
state = state.copyWith(products: changedProduct);
```